# How to export or set a make variable from a shell file

Tags: shell, makefile

I am running a shell script from make environment

I execute the script with input parameters as make variables:

```
/shell_script.sh  $(make_var1) $(make_var2)
```

I process these variables in shell. I want to assign the result from a shell command to the make variable and export back to shell.

```
make_var=shell_command
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not trivial to change the parent environment of a shell-script, one approach is to echo the export statements and source the output of the script in your parent environment:

```
...
echo "export make_var1=${make_var1}"
...
```

and when you launch your script do it using eval:

```
eval $(./shell_script.sh $make_var1 $make_var2)
```

this is the approach taken by for example `ssh-agent`.

A second option is to `source` the script, in that case the script will be run line-by-line in the current shell:

```
 . shell-script.sh
```

any `export` statements in the script will be run in the current shell.